# Xamarin Android Binding Library - does not implement inherited abstract member in DigitalPersona UareU JAR

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, digital-persona-sdk

I am trying Android binding library and I am encountering the below error -

> 'ReaderCollectionImpl' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractList.Get(int)'

and the below function is generated in my class

```
public virtual unsafe global::Com.Digitalpersona.Uareu.IReader Get (int n)
{
}
```

When I try to change the keyword from virtual to override

```
public override unsafe global::Com.Digitalpersona.Uareu.IReader Get (int n)
{
}
```

I get this error -

> 'ReaderCollectionImpl.Get(int)': return type must be 'Object' to match overridden member 'AbstractList.Get(int)'

I cannot change my return type. I also tried using the `new` keyword however it didn't help me out.

The class looks like this in Java native code -

```
public class ReaderCollectionImpl extends AbstractList<Reader> implements ReaderCollection
{
}
```

While converting it in C# it changes to -

```
public partial class ReaderCollectionImpl : global::Java.Util.AbstractList 
{
}
```

My guess is `Java.Util.AbstractList` does not have generics, that might be the issue here?

Comment: May I know if you have found the solution to this issue?

Comment: You have a link for the jar you are trying to bind?

Answer (score 1):

After decompile the dpuareu.jar and look into the original code, I managed to get it compiled without issue by adding these lines in Metadata.xml.

```
 <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.digitalpersona.uareu.dpfpdd']/class[@name='ReaderCollectionImpl']/ method[@name='get']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
 <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.digitalpersona.uareu.dpfpdd']/class[@name='ReaderCollectionImpl.ReaderImpl']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

The next step is to add all the "so" into the project, right click them and select the "Build Action" to "EmbeddedReferenceJar".

[image]

With these setup, I'm able to add reference of the DLL to my Xamarin.Android project and call this line without error. I can even call the GetName() below and get the name of the connected scanner. This should serve as the starting point for further development.

```
    ReaderCollectionImpl readerCollection;

    public ReaderCollectionImpl GetReaders()
    {
        try
        {
            readerCollection = (ReaderCollectionImpl)UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection(Android.App.Application.Context);
            readerCollection.GetReaders();                

            return readerCollection;
        }
        catch(UareUException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public int GetSize()
    {
        return readerCollection.Size();
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return (readerCollection.Get(0) as ReaderCollectionImpl.ReaderImpl).Description.Name;
    }
```